# Meteor editabletext do not work in cascading each

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

I am trying to use the editable text package of barbahams (babrahams:editable-text-wysiwyg-bootstrap-3) to edit the content of an array inside another array in mongodb, Although the outer each seems to work fine as well as the inner (when I put it out of the outer one and manually set the first $ to 0, when I put any editableText inside the inner each it doesn't work at all.

My schema is this:

```
Params = new Mongo.Collection("params");
Params.attachSchema(new SimpleSchema({
    title: {
        type:String,
        label: "title",
    },
    data: {
        type: Array,
        optional: true
    },
    'data.$': {
        type: Object
    },
    'data.$.name': {
        type: String
    },
    'data.$.values': {
        type: Array
    },
    'data.$.values.$': {
        type: String
    },
}));
```

My template is this:

```
<template name="param_edit_form">
    {{#with param}}
        {{#each data}}
            {{#let data_index=@index}}
                {{> editableText context=.. collection='params' field=(get_name @index)}}: <!-- this one works -->
                {{#each values data_index}}
                    <span style="color:#f00;">
                        {{this}} <!-- this one works, it displays the text I want, it's just that it is noe editable -->
                        {{> editableText context=.. collection='params' field=(get_value data_index @index)}}, <!-- this one doesn't work, nor any other editable text -->
                    </span>
                {{/each}}
                        {{> editableText context=.. collection='params' field=(get_value data_index 0)}}, <!-- this one works -->
            {{/let}}
        {{/each}}
    {{/with}}
</template>
```

..and my helpers are these:

```
Template.param_edit_form.helpers({
    param: function(){
        return Params.findOne({_id:Session.get("paramid")});
    },
    // find all visible data
    data: function(){
        if (this.data) {
            return this.data;
        }
    },
    // find all visible values
    values: function()
        if (this.values) {
            return this.values;
        }
    },
    get_name: function(dataIndex){
        return  'data.' + dataIndex + '.name';
    },
    get_value: function(dataIndex, index){
        return  'data.'+dataIndex+'.values.'+index;
    },
});
```

PS: I am sure that I can work around it with an editable div and event listeners etc, it's just that I would like to find out why it doesn't work this way.

Answer (score 0):

I posted the same question at the GitHub repo of the package, it has been answered, so I post the link to that:

https://github.com/JackAdams/meteor-editable-text/issues/79